# (Correction) get portion of array while maintaining indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have an easy question that I can't seem to get my head around. Let say I have an associative array:

```
$myArray = array(
    145 => 'Ferrari', 
    146 => 'Lamborghini', 
    147 => 'Mustang', 
    148 => 'Acura', 
    149 => 'Honda'
);
```

How do I return let say the last n elements from that array while maintaining the key association. I tried array_slice, but I keep getting an empty array

Any help please
Thank you

Comment: Pay attention to what the manual tells you, `array_slice()` can optionally preserve the keys (defaults to not preserving them). http://php.net/array_slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourth parameter of [array_slice is $preserve_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Comment: `array_slice($myArray, -3, 3, TRUE)` should do it

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) with the optional fourth argument

> array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length [, **bool $preserve_keys = false** ]] )

```
$var = array_slice($myArray, -3, 3, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the `preserve_keys` parameter the value of `true` in [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to keep your keys.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with this is the word "last". In an associative array, there is no "first" or "last". So you'll have to define what you want. Do you want the last 3 when sorted alphabetically? etc. Once the question is defined in such terms, the answer will become much more apparent.

Comment: I just want to return a new array with 'car3' => 'Mustang', 
    'car4' => 'Acura', 
    'car5' => 'Honda'

Comment: It's just wrong. And by the way it's even not a real answer. This question is about PHP and in PHP even associative arrays are ordered. This is, because in PHP there is only one kind of array

Comment: @KingCrunch: Yes, internal order, which is generally the (useless) order in which values were put into the array. Ease up on the downvote patrol. :)